# Why does reformatting a successful batch file cause failure?

Tags: batch-file

The following batch file was written by @Compo in another post. It was required by one of my grandchildren at school, so I simply emailed the file as is. It worked perfectly for me and for her.

The batch adds a subdirectory to `E:\Evernote`.

The name of the subdirectory is the date in `yyyy_mm_dd`.

Files are copied from `C:` to the new subdirectory.

```
@Echo Off
Set "sd=C:\EverNote"
Set "dd=E:\EverNote"
Set "ds="
If Not Exist "%sd%\" Exit /B
For /F "Tokens=1-3Delims=/ " %%A In ('RoboCopy/NJH /L "\|" Null'
) Do If Not Defined ds Set "ds=%%A_%%B_%%C"
If Not Defined ds Exit /B
RoboCopy "%sd%" "%dd%\%ds%" /E
```

The heat is now off, but in a few weeks the second part of the project is to submit the documented batch file for marking. My first step was to make the batch more "readable", using rules provided by the school. That means using pairs of parentheses to surround conditional statements, and plenty of "white space" and REM statements.

Problem:  After adding parentheses and white space, with NO alteration to any of the statements (AFAIK), the following reformatted batch fails after a few lines.

```
@Echo Off
Set "sd=C:\EverNote"
Set "dd=E:\EverNote"
Set "ds="

REM The next @echo is respected
@echo "If Not Exist"

REM After the next "Pause", and hitting any key, the batch exits.
REM IMO, that means "Exit /B" is being executed. 
REM In turn, that means "%sd%\" does not exist. Why not?

Pause

If Not Exist "%sd%\" 
(    
    Exit /B
)      

For /F "Tokens=1-3Delims=/ " %%A In ('RoboCopy/NJH /L "\|" Null') Do 
(
    If Not Defined ds 
    (
        Set "ds=%%A_%%B_%%C"
    )
)

If Not Defined ds 
(
    Exit /B
)

RoboCopy "%sd%" "%dd%\%ds%" /E

Pause
```

I would be grateful if someone could explain how a change in formatting can cause failure.

Comment: `(` has to be on the same physical line as `if`

Comment: OldGrantonian, neither you nor myself should be providing work for somebody else's project to be marked. **It is academic dishonesty**,  and your grandchild **does not have my permission to use any part of it** for such purposes!

Comment: Good job reading the help file for the commands you are trying to use. If you would have read them you certainly would not have written the code like that.

Comment: @Compo. On reflection, I absolutely agree with that. I apologize. My grandaughter only has her mother. No-one else in the house. Looks as if my age is catching up with me. And the persistent trolling by someone on this forum and the Dostips forum is probably not helping. It's stressful.

Comment: @OldGrantonian, the backstory is irrelevant, if you truly loved and valued your granddaughter, you'd support their learning through encouragement and advice, not show them that cheating and plagiarism are acceptable behaviors.

Comment: @Compo. You're 100% correct. That's the way it shall be in future.

Comment: @Stephan. That worked fine for all the conditional statements.

Comment: @OldGrantonian, Please delete this question! and BTW had any additional parentheses been necessary I'd have included them in my code, they're not, so please don't bastardise it unnecessarily.

Comment: @OldGrantonian, I am not trolling anyone.  I would say the same thing to any newbie. Just about every day we see someone post a question and I tell them that if they would have read the first X lines of the help file you would see your problem.  Your code shows me plain as day that you did not attempt to read the help file for the IF or FOR commands.

Comment: @Squashman, TBF they didn't have time, _they were too busy doing someone else's math assessment!_

Comment: @Compo: I agree with your point about academic honesty. However, in strict legal terms, you have given up your control over this piece of code, because you licensed it as `cc by-sa 3.0` when posting here (see the footer). The Meta ethos of whether Stack Exchange (and its communities) should be policing students and their helpers is generally "we cannot actively stop people cheating, but we can try to advise". So, don't worry too much about it.

Comment: (Of course, you could argue that the student in question should attribute the work to you, and is not likely to, but that's a slightly different question to wanting to withdraw permission to use it).